# Magento command line error

Tags: magento2

I have install magento on my local host and facing problem. There is no link of add new post and change theme option. Only pages section is showing. So some one told me that i have to run command to enable these feature. But when i run following command then an error occurred.

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

[Snapshot of my command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl7fM.png).

I have install magento in E drive and here is full path

> E:\XAMPP\htdocs\Magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like php environment variable is not set. So you need to add that and then run it.let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I have checked everything. can you help me on team viewer?

Comment: i have set php environment variable. But now showing :-   
     could not open input file : magento

Comment: Are you inside your Magento directory?

Comment: i am very new in magento. can you help me on team viewer? 

I will be very thank full to u

Comment: please check this error     https://i.imgur.com/bpvMNT7.png

Comment: give me teamviewer details

Comment: Sunil Patel 

 Id :- 253 983 907
Password :- 7661